# compare all x with in a group in dfA to all possible y's in the same group in dfB using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

How do i compare all x values for a case in a dataset to every possible y value for a case in another dataset?  that is, compare all x's to y's in these dataframes (df.A and df.B) which are duplicated by case.
dfA

```
  case  x
0    A  1
1    B  2
2    B  3
3    B  4
4    C  5

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

dfB

```
  case  y
0    A  1
1    B  2
2    B  3
3    B  4
4    B  5
```

[5 rows x 2 columns]
to get this dfC

```
  case       date  x y
0    A 2014-03-02  1 T
1    B 2014-02-02  2 T
2    B 2014-03-01  3 T
3    B 2014-04-08  4 T
4    B 2014-02-02  2 F
5    B 2014-03-01  3 F
6    B 2014-04-08  4 F
```

something to work with

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame(
{'case' : pd.Series(["A","B","B","B","C"]), 
 'x' : pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])})

dfB = pd.DataFrame({'case':list('ABBBB'), 'y':list('12345')})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think -- if I understand the problem correctly -- all you need is [pd.merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) (and maybe a call to `sort`):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as DT

dfA = pd.DataFrame(
    {'case' : pd.Series(["A","B","B","B"]), 
     'date' : pd.Series([DT.datetime(2014, 3, 2), DT.datetime(2014, 2,2),
                         DT.datetime(2014, 3, 1), DT.datetime(2014, 2, 8)]),
     'x' : pd.Series([1,2,3,4])})

dfB = pd.DataFrame({'case':list('ABB'), 'y':list('TTF')})

result = pd.merge(dfA, dfB, on=['case'], how='outer')
result.sort(['case','y','x'], ascending=[True,False,True], inplace=True)
print(result)
```

yields

```
  case       date  x  y
0    A 2014-03-02  1  T
1    B 2014-02-02  2  T
3    B 2014-03-01  3  T
5    B 2014-02-08  4  T
2    B 2014-02-02  2  F
4    B 2014-03-01  3  F
6    B 2014-02-08  4  F

[7 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: You are so good... and wow did i over think that.  only problem is that I want to keep all case's from A (adjusted example to be more clear), but i realize that is just how='outer'.  thanks